How to exclude fields of an array using Mongo Projections
I want to only exclude the "Name" field for the "People" array field:
e.g.
"Type" : "Green",
"Date" : "2022-10-21",
"People" : [{
  "RSVP": "Yes",
  "Name": "Peter"
},
{
  "RSVP": "No",
  "Name": "Pan"
},
]

to become:
"Type" : "Green",
"People" : [{
  "RSVP": "Yes"
},
{
  "RSVP": "No"
}
]

Any ideas? Thank you!
I have tried this post: Mongo how to exclude nested _id in the nested array
but I need the projection specifications to be in a list, so how can I do something like:
val fieldList = List("Date", "People.Name???")


you need to put exclusion attribute of the array refer to: https://mongoplayground.net/p/NwEpwQlJe2g
db.collection.find({},
{
  Date: 0,
  _id: 0,
  "People.RSVP": 0
})


is there a way to do something like using Projection.exclude() ?

What driver/language your application is using? as projection supports inclusion or exclusion at field level.
: <1 or true>
Specifies the inclusion of a field. If you specify a non-zero integer for the projection value, the operation treats the value as true.
: <0 or false>
Specifies the exclusion of a field. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.0/reference/method/db.collection.find/#std-label-method-find-projection
